# Can Adobe Illustrator export hidden sublayers as svg group with attribute display="none"?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape

Inkscape can do that, but I've been told Illustrator is not able to export nested layers (sublayers) with attribute display="none". Is this true? If so, how can I have all my hidden sublayers be exported as svg  elements with display="none"?

Comment: Welcome smohadjer. This appears to be more of a technical support question and would probably be better served by asking Adobe.

Comment: As far as I know Adobe has no dedicated technical support site for its products. All I could find online is their community forum in which I have posted the same question, but so far no answer there either: http://forums.adobe.com/message/5734750#5734750

Comment: Whenever I need to do specific code things to SVG exported from Illustrator, I almost always end up doing it in a text editor with find/replace and [regular expressions](http://regexpal.com). Illustrator's SVG support isn't very good, Adobe treat it as an afterthought. You could give layers or groups you want hidden a name ending with say `--hidden` then find/change `--hidden"(.*)style="` for `"\1style="display:none; ` or something like that.